# Getting account status from a client

Tags: ruby

I have the following Ruby method.

```
def get_status(creds)
  client = create_client(creds)
  status = client.account_status
  client.close_session
  status
end
```

Usually I optimize this kind of code by using `tap` or `yield_self`.
I have come up with a way to use these, but it doesn't seem like the nicest way to optimize it.

```
def get_status(creds)
  create_client(creds).yeild_self do |client|
    [client, client.account_status]
  end.yield_self do |client, status|
    client.close_session
    status
  end
end
```

Is my new solution better than the original solution?

Comment: Define _better_ and _optimization_ please. Your review request lacks context.

Comment: [I did encourage you to read the guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63656026/how-to-optimize-ruby-method#comment112565788_63656026), and not to post it as-is. Should I have been more clear?

Answer (score 2):

First of all I also agree with the questions asked that you should define first why you want to optimize this method? With 4 lines of code I think this method is still readable and also your suggested refactoring would more obfuscate this method.

Anyway, here are some suggestions to improve the readability a little bit.

This is just a small refactoring but I think it makes it more clear that you create a 'session' and makes it more reusable. Basically it is just extracting a `with_session` method.

```rb
def get_status(creds)
  with_session(creds) do |session|
    session.account_status
  end
end

def with_session(creds)
  client = create_client(creds)
  result = yield(client)
  client.close_session
  result
end
```

Now the next step could be to adapt the client class (or extract a session class) and move this method in there instead.

```rb
class Session
  def initialize(credentials)
    @credentials = credentials
  end

  def execute
    client = create_client(credentials)
    result = yield(client)
    client.close_session
    result
  end

  private

  attr_reader :credentials
end

def get_status(creds)
  Session.new(creds).execute do |session|
    session.account_status
  end
end
```

In the end your method did not change much but giving it proper names, splitting concerns and moving it to the right place improved in my opinion the code.